# Is this statement equivalent to the definition of the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

$$
\exists \Delta > 0\exists E>0\exists \text{surjective and non-decreasing }h : (0,\Delta) \to (0, E) \forall \delta \in (0,\Delta) \forall x : |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<h(\delta)
$$

I guess this gives more intuitive, equivalent definition of the limit, but it's hard to prove the converse direction(The ordinary $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definiton implies this), especially at the part on the construction of $h$.

I would like to ask whether it's equivalent to the ordinary definition or, there is a counterexample.

Comment: Don't you mean $h(\delta)$ instead of $\epsilon$?

Comment: @PaulFrost That's right. I fixed it. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordinary $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definiton gives us $\delta_n> 0$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta_n$ implies $|f(x)-L|< 1/n$. Now define recursively $\rho_1 = \delta_1$ and $\rho_{n+1} = \min(\rho_n/2, \delta_{n+1})$. Then $(\rho_n)$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of positive numbers (note $\rho_{n+1} \le \rho_n/2$). We also have $\rho_{n+1} \le 2^{-n}\rho_1$, thus $\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty [\rho_{n+1},\rho_n) = (0, \rho_2)$. Let $\Delta = \rho_2, E = 1$. Note that for each $\delta \in (0,\Delta)$ there exists a unique $n \ge 2$ such that  $\delta \in [\rho_{n+1},\rho_n)$. Now define
$$h :(0,\Delta) \to (0,E), h(t) = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{t- \rho_{n+1}}{(n-1)n(\rho_n - \rho_{n+1})} \text{ for } t \in [\rho_{n+1},\rho_n) .$$
Clearly $h(\rho_{n+1}) = \frac{1}{n}$ and $[\rho_{n+1},\rho_n)$ is mapped strictly increasing onto $[\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n-1})$, thus $h$ maps $(0,\Delta)$ strictly increasing onto $(0,1)$.

Let $\delta \in (0,\Delta)$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta$. Take $n \ge 2$ such that $\delta \in [\rho_{n+1},\rho_n)$. This shows that $\delta < \rho_n \le \delta_n$. Hence $|x-x_0|<\delta_n$ which implies
$$|f(x)-L|< 1/n = h(\rho_{n+1}) \le h(\delta) .$$

Comment: At the first line, It seems to be $\delta_n$, and the last line, $\rho_n$ need to be $\rho_{n+1}$. Thanks for the clear proof.

Comment: EDIT) at the last line, $\delta_n$ need to be $\delta$.

Comment: @ChoMedit Typo in the first line corrected. I do not see what the problem in the last line is, but I tried to make more transparent what is going on here.

Comment: I think everything is okay now. Great job.